# TCP IO Akka socket connection closed is not called when Internet is down

Tags: scala, tcp, connection, akka

I have implemented a socket - client interaction using akka's TCP module. I am trying to make the application to detect when the socket is closed and release the resources assigned to that client's socket.

Akka has case  _ : ConnectionClosed case in order to handle this kind of situation.But i have realized that it is not being called when the internet connection is down.

I couldn't be able to find anything to detect that the socket's client part is disconnected from the internet.

Is there any specifics that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network connection going down doesn't necessarily close any sockets, the OS is free to leave them open in case the network connection recovers. I believe this is really an issue with your OS, and not with Akka. TCP connections will eventually timeout, but this can take tens of minutes. See [TCP Socket no connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085676/tcp-socket-no-connection-timeout).

Comment: Now i see that was the main problem. I haven't thought that it would be 2 hours for a connection to drop. Solution for me was changing the OS parameters "echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time","echo 5 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
","echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes"