# When is a TCP connection considered idle?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, keep-alive, retransmit-timeout

I have a requirement to enable TCP keepalive on any connections and now I am struggling with the results from our test case. I think this is because I do not really understand when the first keepalive probe is sent. I read the following in the documentation for `tcp_keepalive_time` on Linux:

> the interval between the last data packet sent (simple ACKs are not considered data) and the first keepalive probe; after the
>   connection is marked to need keepalive, this counter is not used any
>   further

Some other sources state that this is the time a connection is idle, but they do not further define what this means. I also looked into Stevens to find a more formal definition of this, because I am wondering what "the last data packet sent" actually means when considering retransmissions.

In my test case, I have a connection where data is only sent from a server to a client at rather high rates. To test keepalive, we unplugged the cable on the client's NIC. I can now see that the network stack tries to send the data and enters the retransmission state, but no keep alive probe is sent. Is it correct that keep alive probes are not sent during retransmission?

Comment: If you are 'sending at rather high rates' your 'requirement to enable TCP keepalive' doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @EJP We have other connections that e.g. do not send any data, and others that send only at low rates. Additionally, it is a requirement directly imposed on us by our customer. They use it globally.

Comment: I assume you are referring to setting SO_KEEPALIVE on all your connections (the default is "off")?  If so you'll only see a keepalive packet after (default on linux is 2 hours) but then the unplug trick should work (if it's sending no other data).

Comment: @rogerdpack Yes, we had to enable keep alive on all connections by default as a mandatory customer requirement. The time until the first keep alive packet is sent also includes the TCP retry time. cnicutar's answer provides the details.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I have a connection where data is only sent from a server to a client
> at rather high rates.

Then you'll never see keepalives. Keepalives are sent when there is "silence on the wire". [RFC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) has some explanation re keepalives.

> A "keep-alive" mechanism periodically probes the other end of a
> connection **when the connection is otherwise idle**, even when there is
> no data to be sent

Back to your question:

> Some other sources state that this is the time a connection is idle,
> but they do not further define what this means.

This is how long TCP will wait before poking the peer "hoy! still alive?".

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
7200
```

In other words, you've been using a TCP connection and it has been great. However, for the past 2 hours there hasn't been anything to send. Is it reasonable to assume the connection is still alive? Is it reasonable to assume all the middleboxes in the middle still have state about your connection? Opinions vary and keepalives aren't part of RFC793.

> The TCP specification does not include a keep-alive mechanism  it
> could:  (1) cause perfectly good connections to break during transient
> Internet failures; (2) consume unnecessary bandwidth ("if no one is
> using the connection, who cares if it is still good?")

---

> To test keepalive, we unplugged the cable on the client's NIC.

This isn't testing keepalive. This is testing your TCPs retransmit strategy, i.e. how many times and how often TCP will try to get your message across. On a Linux box this (likely) ends up testing [`net.ipv4.tcp_retries2`](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.kernel.obscure.html):

> How may times to retry before killing alive TCP connection. RFC 1122
> says that the limit should be longer than 100 sec. It is too small
> number. Default value 15 corresponds to  13-30min depending on RTO.

But [RFC5482 - TCP User Timeout Option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5482) provides more ways to influence it.

> The TCP user timeout controls how long transmitted data may remain
> unacknowledged before a connection is forcefully closed.

Back to the question:

> Is it correct that keep alive probes are not sent during retransmission

It makes sense: TCP is already trying to elicit a response from the other peer, an empty keepalive would be superfluous.

---

#### Linux-specific (2.4+) [options to influence keepalive](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)

> - `TCP_KEEPCNT` The maximum number of keepalive probes TCP should send before dropping the connection.
> - `TCP_KEEPIDLE` The time (in seconds) the connection needs to remain idle before TCP starts sending keepalive probes, if the socket option `SO_KEEPALIVE` has been set on this socket
> - `TCP_KEEPINTVL` The time (in seconds) between individual keepalive probes

#### Linux-specific (2.6.37+) [option to influence TCP User Timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)

> `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` The maximum amount of time in
> milliseconds that transmitted data may remain unacknowledged before
> TCP will forcibly close connection.

So for example your application could use this option to determine how long the connection survives when there is no connectivity (similar to your NIC-unplugging example). E.g. if you have reason to believe the client will come back (perhaps they closed the laptop lid? spotty wireless access?) you can specify a timeout of 12 hours and when they do come back the connection will still function.

Comment: FYI, Linux 2.4+ has `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL` and `TCP_KEEPCNT` options for `setsockopt()` to set the idle time before probing begins, the time interval between probes, and the max number of probes to send, respectively.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Neat. Feel free to edit the answer to point that out!

Comment: @cnicutar Do you have a source I can reference which describes that no keepalive probes are sent during retransmission? It seems that this differs from system to system, e.g. on Windows it seems to be different.

Comment: @Jens I don't have a source. It is not illegal to keep sending keepalive probes but it makes little sense: if TCP is already sending stuff, there is already reason for the other side to ACK (which would prove the connection is alive).

Comment: @cnicutar great answer. It could be improved slightly by also including information on TCP_USER_TIMEOUT on linux. It seems like the OP and others will want to know how to set per connection re-transmission timeout when searching for answers on why keep alive only works on connections that are idle or that are waiting for data that doesn't arrive.

Comment: @KurtM I added a few more details. Feel free to edit the answer to add anything you think is useful.