# Detect TCP Packet Loss

Tags: java, c++, c, tcp

I am experiementing with verification of TCP protocol and its loss-tolerance feature. In a client and server pair, I want to detect retransmission of packets for which there is no acknoledgement due to lost packets. TCP does retransmission but is there a way to programmatically detect this in client / server program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the retransmission rules for TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956685/what-are-the-retransmission-rules-for-tcp)

Comment: Python compiles down to C and there are many useful packages. Not sure if there is a way, but python will help you avoid writing pages of code.

Comment: It may be useful to get a [packet analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_packet_analyzers)

Comment: you could use netstat as stated http://serverfault.com/questions/318909/how-passively-monitor-for-tcp-packet-loss-linux, you need just to call this from your program

Answer (score 2):

**Method1: Check retransmission with sequence number**

If the packet is retransmitted, its sequence number remains the same. You can store the all sequence numbers of all transmitted packets. At each transmission check if you've already encountered this sequence number. If you have, its a retransmission. It you havent, add it to the data structure.

**Method2: Out of order transmissions**

As packet sequence number remains the same in retransmission and because of the fact that sequence numbers increase monotonically. You can check if for every transmission if the sequence number of current packet is less than the previous packet. If it is, its a retransmission.

Sidenote: This is how packet analyzers like WireShark mark packets as retransmissions

Comment: I think the hard question is not how to mark retransmissions *given the necessary data to do so*, but how to get to that data.